# To print 'Not Connected' only when the API returns 'null' string with 401 UNAUTHORISED in Vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, mustache

I am new to Vuejs and I need some help in order to solve this one.

What I am excepting is whenever my API returns like image below i.e. null with 401 UNAUTHORISED STATUS, I want to display NOT CONNECTED. And whenever my API returns 201 STATUS OK, I want to display CONNECTED. I really don't have any idea.

Here is my API response:

[image]

Below i am sharing my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="api_data">
    <span class="trick_not_ok" v-if="errorMsg" >Not connected</span>
    <span class="trick_ok" v-if = "noerror" >Connected</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: Api_data,
  data () {
    return {
      Value: [],
      errorMsg: '',
      noerror: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get('https://my_api_goes_here/doubt/')
      .then((response) => { this.Value = response.data })
      .catch((error) => { 
         if(error.response.status === 401){
             this.errorMsg = ''
         }
         else{
             this.noError = ''
         }
         console.log(error) 
       })
  }
}
</script>
```

If I do it this way, nothing is displayed on my page. And in console I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (UNAUTHORIZED). Please someone help me with this by sending me the modified code.

Comment: You have to change code server side.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that because I have no idea of it, as i am dealing it for the first time.

Comment: Can you post the value of `console.log(error)`? I would like to see the data structure you are receiving

Comment: Currently I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (UNAUTHORIZED).

Comment: What I am excepting is whenever my API returns like the above image in my question i.e. null with 401 UNAUTHORISED result, i want to print NOT CONNECTED. And whenever my API returns 201 STATUS OK, i want to print CONNECTED. I don't know how to do it, please help me if you have some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve the desired result rewriting some logic from your code.
In this code, I just changed 3 things:

- the template condition from if.

  `<span class="trick_ok" v-if="errorMsg !== ''" >Not connected</span>`
- Added new variable in data(), it is the same used in template

  `errorMsg: ''`
- changed `catch` to receive a value in case of error (catch clause)

The resulting code would be something like:

```
<template>
  <div class="api_data">
    <span class="trick_ok" v-if="errorMsg !== ''" >Not connected</span>
    <span v-if="connected !== ''" >Connected</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: Api_data,
  data () {
    return {
      Value: [],
      errorMsg: '',
      connected: '',
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get('https://my_api_goes_here/doubt/')
      .then((response) => { 
          this.Value = response.data
          this.connected = 'ok'
          this.errorMsg = ''
       })
      .catch((error) => { 
          console.log(error)
          this.connected = ''
          this.errorMsg = 'Detail: ' +error
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

This code is not tested. But you can have an idea.

The main objective is show message  `not connected` if there is any error in request.

There is some considerations you have to check the status code in the catch function, because if you receive an error like 403 or 500 in the way I implemented it still will show the message  `not connected` and perhaps it is not what you want.

So in catch clause maybe you need to check for the status code number too.

```
.catch((error) => { 
     //if (status === 401) {
     //    this.errorMsg = 'Detail: ' +error
     //}
})
```

I left this code commented because you should figure out a way to get the status code from the error from the parameter in catch clause.

Comment: Yeah thank you, you got my objective right but both the logic that you have sent me dint work out, and even I tried other things but dint work out, can you please give me some other ideas about this.

Comment: what is the error msg? i will try to run this code. One way to do it is like this.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (UNAUTHORIZED). This is what I am getting in my console, As i said you earlier i want to print NOT CONNECTED if the status is 401 UNAUTHORISED and CONNECTED if my API returns 201 OK STATUS.

Comment: Just update answer, can you check if it work? And by the way http status 201 is created. You can check this information here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Even this did not work out, again i am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) in my console. But if i use if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
     this.errorMsg = 'Detail: ' + error
    } , then i am getting GET https://my_api_goes_here/doubt/ with 401 UNAUTHORISED, please do help me with this issue

Comment: do you have any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

if your response look like these on

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Unauthorized! Access Token was expired!",
  "error_code": 500
}
```

so, in vue2 ( vue.js )

```
.catch(err => {
err.response.data.message // here to access the message json
})
```